# Can't add alt attribute to image_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image

What is a propper way of adding alt attribute to image_tag in rails?
I have tried these options, and they are giving me a syntax error or alt is just not showing:

```
<%= image_tag @product.asset.url, alt: "#{@product.name} image", class: 'w-100' %>

<%= image_tag (@product.asset.url, alt: "#{@product.name} image"), class: 'w-100' %>

<%= image_tag (@product.asset.url, alt: "#{@product.name} image", class: 'w-100') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work fine.

```
<%= image_tag(@product.asset.url, alt: "#{@product.name} image", class:'w-100') %>
```

Comment: This code works but only in production mode, as well as my previous versions. It looks like alt just don't work in my app in development mode. Thank you